# Postgresql 9.x: return custom type from a function

Tags: function, types, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to return a Custom type from a PostgreSQL function as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE myType as 
( 
    "Name" character varying
    ,"Surname" Text
 );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.xml_to_type(inputXml xml)
  RETURNS SETOF myType AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    xml_content myType;
BEGIN

    FOR xml_content in 
        SELECT 
        (xpath('//Name/text()',testColumn))[1]::text::character varying as "Name"
        ,(xpath('//Surname/text()',testColumn))[1]::text::text as "Surname"
        FROM unnest(xpath('//myNodes/node',inputXml)) AS t(testColumn)
    LOOP

    RETURN NEXT xml_content;
    END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

From PostgreSQL query tool it works:

```
SELECT * FROM xml_to_type('<myNodes>
        <node>
            <Name>Alex</Name>
            <Surname>Red</Surname>
        </node>
        <node>
            <Name>Tony</Name>
            <Surname>Stark</Surname>
        </node>
    </myNodes>'::xml);
```

and returns correctly 2 records. The problem is when I call this function from another function:

```
    DECLARE myTypeVar myType[];
    SELECT * FROM xml_to_type(xmlExample) INTO myTypeVar;
```

I get this exception:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "Alex"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Show the output when you run it directly from the query tool.

Comment: The output are two records with two colums, Name and Surname values...

Comment: **Show** the output. Copy. Paste.

Comment: Name            Surname
---------------------------------------------
Alex               Red
Tony              Stark

Comment: For future, add extra info by editing original question. From this there's no way to tell which field is which etc. But that's enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

A function that returns `SETOF x` cannot have its result stored into a field of type `x[]`. Sets are not arrays.

You must use `array_agg`:

```
SELECT  array_agg(x) FROM xml_to_type(xmlExample) x INTO myTypeVar;
```